# Duplicate UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'd like to display the same UIView multiple times. At the moment, I have my drawing in a primary UIView, then copy this into an image using renderInContext: and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext. Then I set the contents of the other proxy UIViews to be this image.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

 [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

 UIImage * clonedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return [clonedImage CGImage];
```

I'm experiencing a bottleneck in the renderInContext: call, presumably because it has to copy the image of the view. I'm seeing hot spots in resample_byte_h_3cpp and resample_byte_v_Ncpp, but I'm not sure what these are doing.

Is it possible to display the same UIView multiple times to reduce this overhead? Or is there a more efficient way to render the image?

Comment: What kind of UIView are you referring to?

Comment: It's a UIView descendant with a background image and some CAShapeLayer overlays.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a copy of the UIImage instead of generating new images over and over from the UIView?

```
//.. Create the clonedImage from UIView

CGImageRef cgImageRef = [clonedImage CGImage];
UIImage *twinImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImageRef];

//.. Use the images

[clonedImage release]; // if needed
[twinImage release]; // if needed
```

Comment: I'm updating the source UIView, and I'd like to see those updates across all of the proxies. I may just put up with the minor lag on the iPhone 3G for this release (about 100-200ms) and re-write this bit of the app using OpenGL in the future. It runs fine as-is on the iPad.

Comment: OK, then you should check out Grand Central Dispatch. It allows you to setup queues and run code in batches, dependent on when certain code is done. It'll also run in the background, which doesn't look up the app and/or it's UI.